# How to send and receive over sockets in C++ in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to do this

For the server:

```
QTcpServer qtp;
qtp.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1440);
qtp.readFromClient(); //What is the name of the method to read the byte from a  client ???
qtp.close();
```

For the client

```
QTcpClient client;
client.connect("127.0.0.1", 1440);
client.sendData(myString); // What is the name of the method to do this ???  
client.close();
```

I did not find a method name in QTcpServer to retrieve data and in QTcpClient to send data. What are the methods names to do that ?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the methods available reading the documentation. In [this link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html) there is the documentation for QAbstractSocket Class inherited by QTcpSocket.

Anyway the methods you want to use are `write()` to send data and you can check if data is available to read with `bytesAvailable()` and read data with `read()` or `readData()`. These las methods are inherited and reimplemented from QIODevice Class, that you can also find in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html).

Comment: Yes, but it is too hard, ... I did not find the method name to retrieve data in this link, nor to send data...

Comment: I have edited the answer with names of the methods and links to the documentation that you should read.